# finding the volume of a bounded area

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $V$ be the bounded area by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=10-x^2-2y^2$. find the volume of $V$.

Could we use something like cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The first step could be to visualize the space:

[image]

Note: just for your check, the volume turns out to be $\frac{25\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\pi$.

---

Addendum:

From $10-x^2-2y^2=x^2+y^2$ you obtain $2x^2+3y^2=10$. Hence the volume will be $$V=\int\int_{2x^2+3y^2\leq10}(z_1-z_2)dxdy$$ or

\begin{align}
V&=\int_{y=-\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}}^{y=\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}}\int_{x=-\sqrt{10-\frac32y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{10-\frac32y^2}}(10-2x^2-3y^2)dxdy\\
&=...\\
&=\frac{25\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\pi
\end{align}
... the integrals are standard ...

Here is also a yet another graph of the volume you are after

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got the intuition.
In my opinion if the project of the area to $xy$ plane was a circle, it was appropriate to use cylindrical coordinates. but since the project is an oval, I can not do anything.

Comment: Would you please give me a little hint how to write boundaries of the triple integral?

Comment: Sure, see the addendum.